How to implement hard negative mining for PyTorch RetinaNet_v2 object detection model?
I am currently using the PyTorch object detection model retinanet_resnet50_fpn_v2. I want to implement hard negative mining, such that I take the top X images with the highest loss in training, and only use these to train the next epoch.
I assume to do this I need to have the image level loss, however when running loss_dict = model(images,targets) I am just getting a summation over all images in the batch. Is there an easy way to pull out the individual image losses? Thanks
During training I run the code below:
    for images, targets in metric_logger.log_every(data_loader, print_freq, header):
        images, targets = list(images), list(targets)
        images = [x.to(device) for x in images]
        targets = [{k: v.to(device) if isinstance(v, torch.Tensor) else v for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]
        with torch.cuda.amp.autocast(enabled=scaler is not None):
            loss_dict = model(images, targets)
            losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())

       ...

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        if scaler is not None:
            scaler.scale(losses).backward()
            scaler.step(optimizer)
            scaler.update()
        else:
            losses.backward()
            optimizer.step()

```


WIth pytorch you can calculate the losses yourself using whatever loss function you want, which would give you the image losses. You can then sort and select the loss values you want to use to calculate the gradients.
